# Conditional expectation of the sum of three dice rolls given the sum of their maximum and product

Tags: probability

Consider the random experiment in which three fair dice are rolled simultaneously (and independently). 
Let $X$ be the random variable defined as the sum of the values of these three dice. 
Let $Y_1$ be the maximum of the three values, let $Y_2$ be their product, and let $Y=Y_1+Y_2$. 
Finally, define $Z=E[X∣Y]$ (the conditional expectation of $X$ given $Y$).

Find the expected value of the random variable $Z$. Enter your answer as a fraction, such as $\frac{3}{2}$.

I would like some help on where to start this problem, please. I know $X$ can be any value between $3$ and $18$ and $Y_2$ could be (most of the values) between $1$ and $216$; i.e., $Y_2$ will never be $7$, $11$, $13$, etc. since those numbers are prime and are greater than $6$.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the Law of Total Expectation (aka the Law of Iterated Expectations)?

Comment: I know it as the Tower Rule, but yeah, I do

Comment: Well... what does it say? And do you see why it might be relevant here?

Comment: Note that the title you gave your post is misleading. You aren't asked to find the conditional expectation of $X$ given $Y$. You're asked to find the **expected value of** the conditional expectation of $X$ given $Y$.

Comment: It states E(X) = Ey(Ex|y(X|Y)) And no... I don't really see it yet.

Comment: And thanks, I fixed the title

Comment: E[Z]=E[E[X|Y]]=???

Comment: I see! I can probably get it from there. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

The expected value of a die roll is 3.5. Thus, for three independent rolls, the expected value is 10.5. $\frac{21}{2}$, if you're being picky.

Conditional expectation has the following property, known as averaging: $E( E(X|Y) ) = EX$.

Comment: thanks a lot man, i actually think i understand how you got that